# PHP, How to display the 2nd table

Tags: php

DBOperations.php

```php
public function getByQRID($id){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT students.*, courses.* FROM students INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id = students.course_id WHERE students.id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Update the code

Comment: which one is the second table..? the Course one? you can join the Student table to Course table.. something like `SELECT s.id AS id, s.name AS name, c.course AS course FROM students AS s LEFT JOIN courses AS c s.id ON c.course_id = id WHERE id = ?`. though i'm wondering why its `books` instead of student on your question.. btw, you can find sql tutorial on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Comment: You need to read about SQL JOINS. We can help with specific questions on issues with using Joins, but for general training an SQL tutorial is your best bet.

Comment: @BagusTesa the course table is the 2nd table

Comment: @BagusTesa so I'll just join both table?

Comment: @mrunion thank you very sir

Comment: books, courses, students... it's 3 tables. Which 2 tables do you want to join?

Comment: This `"s"` should be `"i"` since we're dealing with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using MySql, then try this:

```
select * from Student 
inner join Course on Student.course_id = Course.id
where Student.id = 1
```

(1 it's an example, and I'm guessing things, since your question wasn't entirely clear).

I hope it helps!